# Animate a chart by series in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, animation, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to animate a chart by series in PowerPoint using VBA. Here is my code:

```
With PPSlide.Shapes(1)
    With .AnimationSettings
        .EntryEffect = msoAnimEffectFade
        .ChartUnitEffect = ppAnimateBySeries
        .Animate = True
    End With
End With
```

I encounter an two errors depending on order of operations. If I attempt to execute `.ChartUnitEffect` first, I get and error"
Animation Settings (unknown member) : Invalid REquest. Sorry, you can't set chart effects on objects that are not charts.

[image]

The shape object `PPSlide.Shapes(1)` is definitely my chart. According to Microsoft, this shape type e is a chart. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype) here.

```
Debug.Print PPSlide.Shapes(1).type
```

3

If I switch the order of operations so that I attempt to execute `.EntryEffect = msoAnimEffectFade` first, I get this error: Animation Settings (unknown member) : Invalid Enumeration Value.

[image]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.animationsettings.chartuniteffect) from Microsoft looks pretty straightforward. Any help would be massively amazing.

Comment: [Looking around](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98c5d089-d00f-409b-83b2-a8d319babc61/using-the-chartuniteffect-property?forum=vsto) this could be an old persistent bug.  I'm getting the same issues.  However, for the `.EntryEffect`, does `ppEffectFade` do the trick for you?

Comment: Thank you @BruceWayne. `ppEffectFade` does in fact remove the enumeration error noted in the question! Where did you find that documentation. It has the effect of animating the whole shape, in this case, the chart. I was also able to accomplish animating the chart with: `PPSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect shape:=PPShape, effectId:=msoAnimEffectFade`.